# Table overflowing a div doesn't show scrollbars in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an issue with a nested table that is taller than the screen - should be restrained in height, with scrollbars appearing, but the table just grows to full size, eventually being cut off at the bottom of the screen.

Almost the exact same issue is described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587737/html-table-height-and-scroll-div-behavior-in-ie11-and-chrome), but there's no answer. It works on Chrome and IE with compatibility view turned on, but does this in IE11 and firefox.

Here is the other question's jsfiddle example, which duplicates the issue simply. Scrollbars on chrome, nothing on IE: https://jsfiddle.net/f473xudf/17/

I've spent a long time fiddling with heights with little luck. Ideas, anyone?

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black; height:100px">
<tr>
<td >
   Caption
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>
  <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height:100%">
    <table>
      <tr>
          <td>
            Line1
          </td>
       </tr> 
      <tr>
           <td>
            Line2
          </td>
       </tr>   
      <tr>
          <td>
            Line3
          </td>
       </tr>   
      <tr>
          <td>
            Line4
          </td>
       </tr>        
    </table>      
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```